# Unable to understand this xquery statement

Tags: xquery

I am new to xquery and unable to understand what does it means :

```
$bottles=getallBottles()
$cups=getallCups()

<containers>
{
($bottles,$cups)  //this line i am unable to get
}
<containers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma forms a sequence.  Presumably `$bottles` is a sequence of zero-to-many items and `$cups` is a sequence of zero-to-many items.  The comma forms a sequence of all of the items in `$bottles` and all of the items in `$cups`.

For example:

```
let $x := (1, 2, 3)
let $y := ('a', 'b', 'c')
return ($x,$y)
```

yields:

```
1 2 3 a b c
```

In the above example, the parentheses are necessary so that forming the sequence of `$x, $y` takes precedence over `return` and the entire constructed sequence is returned.

In an example similar to the original question, parentheses are unnecessary because precedence is not ambiguous:

```
let $x := <a><x>5</x><x>6</x></a>
let $y := <b><y>1</y><y>2</y></b>
return <container>{$x, $y}</container>
```

yields:

```
<container><a><x>5</x><x>6</x></a><b><y>1</y><y>2</y></b></container>
```

Comment: It is the comma "operator" that forms the sequence, the original example would work without the parenthesis, like your second example would work with `<container>{$x, $y}</container>` instead of `<container>{($x, $y)}</container>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks.  Edited to indicate correct purpose of comma and parentheses.